# Twig For Loop - Problems

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, twig

i need to do the following:

```
<li id="a"><a name="a" class="title">A</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Adam<span>UserID</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

I have a array with usernames and need to sort them like above. The Big **A** in

```
<li id="a"><a name="a" class="title">A</a>
```

is the first character of the Username. So if i have for example a User with the Name "TechnoMan" then it must be like this:

```
<li id="t"><a name="t" class="title">T</a>
```

ANd of course "**Adam**" should be replaced with the Username

Currently the Array looks like that:

```
Array
(
    [T] => Array
        (
            [1] => TechnoMan
        )
    [W] => Array
        (
            [18] => Wulf
            [23] => WantYou
        )

)
```

**T** is the first character of the Usernames, and [1] ist the Userid, TechnoMan is the username in this example.

How can i get these list with twig and their for?

Im completly clueless.  If its needed i can make changes to the array aswell, i just thought there is no way to find out the first character of the usernames in twig, so i sorted them already in PHP.

Thanks for any reply.

Michael

Comment: Take a look at [for - Documentation - Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys)

Comment: I already did. Still no clue how i should do it. My problem is the design of the array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP :

```
$array = array();
$array['T'] = array(1 => 'TechnoMan');
$array['W'] = array(18 => 'Wulf', 23 => 'WantYou');
```

Twig :

```
{% for key, users in array %}
    <li id="{{ key }}"><a name="{{ key }}" class="title">{{ key }}</a>
    <ul>
        {% for key2, user in users %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ user }}<span>{{ key2 }}</span></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This outputs :

```
<li id="T"><a name="T" class="title">T</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">TechnoMan<span>1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="W"><a name="W" class="title">W</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Wulf<span>18</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WantYou<span>23</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Oh well, yeah i am a bit dumb :D. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate this. Michael